# How to create a navigation bar using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap I know to create a basic navigation bar in bootstrap I want to know how to create a navigation bar same like in http://demo.vnthemepro.com/vt_ovansport/?___store=default

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
         <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Smart</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
     </div>
     <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="help/">Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="about/">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact/">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need Bootstrap to do this at all!

Comment: I want to do it using bootstrap only @Arqetech

Comment: If It would be without Bootstrap I'd surely Help. Sorry though, I don't like the bootstrap nav system!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div role="navigation" class="row navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" aria-expanded="false"> Shop <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"> DIY Guides <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">EPDM Calculator <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" aria-expanded="false"> Adhesives &amp; Sealants <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"> Trade<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Tutorials <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>                                
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```